# How can I tell if the variable involed in a instruction in KLEE is symbolic or concrete

Tags: variables, concrete, klee

I want to know if there is a way to tell if a variable is symbolic or not in KLEE when KLEE is executing an instruction involving the variable.

Comment: There is no such thing as an instruction is symbolic or concrete. It is just data accessed by an instruction at current context is symbolic will be evaluated symbolically, otherwise it will be evaluated concretely for efficiency reason.

Comment: @user please read the question again. My question asks whether the variable is symbolic or concrete not the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for this purpose.

```
/* Return true if the given value is symbolic (represented by an
* expression) in the current state. This is primarily for debugging
* and writing tests but can also be used to enable prints in replay
* mode.
*/
unsigned klee_is_symbolic(uintptr_t n);
```